# How can I configure visual studio to produce a c# executable with a .dll extension

Tags: .net, dll, executable

I have two projects in my solution, the second produces an executable of type 'Windows Application' with a Startup Object defined. I don't want the exe file this project produces to sit in the same directory as my application called 'whatever.exe', I want to rename it to 'whatever.dll', since the user is not intended to run this application manually (in the first process I call Process.Start() with this file as the target - as long as the PE header identifies it as an executable file windows can execute it just fine).

I can simply manually rename the output of the second project to .dll, even automate it in a post build step, but is there a way instead to create a project of type 'Class Library' and define a Startup Object for it?

Comment: OOI why not create a library project and simply reference this library from your main exe project? This would be the standard way of using a library.

Comment: Because if I simply create it as a library project it's not marked as an executable binary, and calling Process.Start() on it will fail.

Comment: If you reference it as a library then you can directly call any public methods from your exe project. You do not need to launch it as a separate process unless you need some specific behaviour that this offers.

Comment: I know, my problem is not with calling public methods on it. It's with running it as a seperate process with Process.Start("whatever.exe") or Process.Start("Whatever.dll") - both of those work if I compile my 'Whatever' project as a 'Windows Application', neither of those work if I compile it as a 'Class Library'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio cannot be specifically configured to give exe projects an extension other than "exe" (you have already mentioned a post-build step, but this is not direct).